# Product filters by variation show wrong products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m having issues trying to understand how to fix a bug I have on my website.

Here's the link to the already filtered product grid: https://marymoonlight.com/fiori-hash-trinciati/?filter_formato=1-kg

I have set that the second product you see in the page (Galaxy Kush) doesn’t even have a 1KG variation in it (on the staging website we have it, but it’s disabled) yet when you apply the 1KG filter you see that product, but you should not!

The filters we’re using (the ones you see above the product grid) are standard WooCommerce widget put in a “sidebar” that has been placed there.

We have a lot of plugins installed on this website, mostly from YITH, but no plugin about filters, sorting or that kind of stuff.

Is there a way to fix this? Has anyone else had this issue before?

Additional info:

- WooCommerce: 4.7.0
- WordPress: 5.5.3

EDIT:
I tried switching to storefront theme and disabling all of the plugins except for woocommerce and the issue is still there.
It doesn't show the product if it doesn't have the variation, but it will show the product if the variation is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In the single product view of *Galaxy Kush* there are 1kg variations available as other products. The disabled are not working properly. Check variations of the product properly. They are still active.